# nginx rewrite rule error: invalid number of arguments in "location"

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx rewrite rule for WebP images that the docs for a plugin said to add, but it's causing the error "invalid number of arguments in 'location'". My hosting support wasn't able to fix the issue. Is anyone able spot what's wrong here?

```
location ~* ^(/. )\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$ {
  add_header Vary Accept;
 
  if ($http_accept ~* "webp"){
    set $imwebp A;
  }
  if (-f $request_filename.webp) {
    set $imwebp  "${imwebp}B";
  }
  if ($imwebp = AB) {
    rewrite ^(.*) $1.webp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression contains a space. Therefore, without quotes it is interpreted as two separate arguments, `^(/.` and `)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$`.

Correct syntax for Nginx: `location ~* "^(/. )\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$" { }`

However,

- the regular expression seems strange, too. First, `/` is unexpected here if not escaped, and the match group `(\/. )` means "one `/` character, any single character and space". Did you mean:

  `^(\/.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$`
- [If is Evil… when used in location context](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: Thank you! My web host (WP Engine) said the rule is no longer causing issues. I used `location ~* "^(\/.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$" {` for the first line